# Получить ссылку - jsoup

Tags: java, android

Получил данные из `Elements metaOgTitle = doc.select("meta[property=og:image]");`

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://p16-va-default.akamaized.net/img/tos-maliva-p-0068/f321e047290d46238480727e7d3785a6~tplv-tiktok-play.image">
```

как из этих данных получить ссылку http://p16-va-default.akamaized.net/img/tos-maliva-p-0068/f321e047290d46238480727e7d3785a6~tplv-tiktok-play.image

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например можно так:

```
Elements metaOgImage = document.select("meta[property=og:image]");
if (metaOgImage != null) {
    String imgurl = metaOgImage.first().attr("content");
}
```

[вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34460055/android-how-to-fetch-or-get-specific-image-from-any-url-or-link-as-like-faceboo) есть подобный вопрос.